# How do I get the CC 2.0 and 3.0 compilers to generate FMA instructions?

Tags: cuda

I'm attempting to run a performance test by generating a series of FMA instructions. However, I can't seem to get the CC 2.0 and CC 3.0 compilers to generate FMA instructions.

If I compile:

```
for (float x = 0; x < loop; x++) {
  a += x * loop;
  a += x * loop;
  ... (6 more repetitions)
}
```

Where `loop` is also a float, I get the following for each line of `a += x * loop;`:

**compute_10,sm_10**:

```
    a += x * loop;
0x0001ffa0  [0103] mov.f32 %f11, %f2;  
0x0001ffa0                  MOV R3, R2;  
0x0001ffa8  [0104] ld.param.f32 %f12, [__cudaparm__Z6kernelPfifS__loop];  
0x0001ffa8                  MOV32I R2, 0x28;  
0x0001ffb0                  LDC R2, c[0x0][R2];  
0x0001ffb8  [0105] mov.f32 %f13, %f4;  
0x0001ffb8                  MOV R0, R0;  
0x0001ffc0  [0106] mad.f32 %f14, %f12, %f13, %f11;  
0x0001ffc0                  FFMA.FTZ R2, R2, R0, R3;  
0x0001ffc8  [0107] mov.f32 %f2, %f14;  
0x0001ffc8                  MOV R2, R2;
```

**compute_30,sm_30**:

```
    a += x * loop;
0x00044688  [0101] mul.f32 %f14, %f30, %f7;  
0x00044688                       FMUL R5, R4, R0;  
0x00044690  [0102] add.f32 %f15, %f13, %f14;  
0x00044690                       FADD R3, R3, R5;
```

That is, when compiling for CC 3.0, I get FMUL/FADD instructions instead of FFMA. When compiling for CC 1.0, I get an FFMA instruction.

I also get this result on a CC 2.0 compiler with `compute_20,sm_20`, and on both release and debug builds.

I have tried to specify `-use_fast_math` and `--fmad=true`. I created the projects with the CUDA 4.2 and 5.0 wizards and made no changes in the default settings.

Environments:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Visual Studio 2010
- CUDA 4.2 + CUDA 5.0 (5.0 installed on top of 4.2)
- GPU: Single GTX660
- Nsight 3.0 RC1

and

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Visual Studio 2010
- CUDA 4.2
- Nsight 2.2
- GPU: Single GTX570

Comment: What is the value of `loop`?

Comment: @Mikhail: `loop` is a float kernel argument. I've been passing in a value of 100.0f.

Comment: I had no trouble generating fma instructions on cc2.0 using cuda 5.0 and a very simple kernel.  Perhaps you could post a complete, compilable example.  Here's [an example](http://pastebin.com/2ZAQmGa8) of what I did, albeit on linux.

Comment: I wonder if this is the correct choice for optimal performance. See this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011708/fmad-false-gives-good-performance .

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I compiled your example for CC 2.0 and still got an FMUL/FADD pair for each `c += a * a;`.

Comment: I get a sequence of fmul/fadd also if I specify `-G` switch.  Can you inspect or provide your complete compile command line?

Comment: @RobertCrovella: That clued me in. I have been adding the `-G` switch to the Release build in order to be able to set a breakpoint and watch the disassembly in the IDE. Removing the `-G` and looking at the .ptx temporary file instead, shows FMAs being generated. Would you add an answer? This is a bug in the compiler, IMO, because generating debug info shouldn't affect which code gets generated.

Comment: So, ahem, contrary to what I said, I guess I did change the default settings for the Release build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the `-G` switch to nvcc affects code generation and also generates additional debug info (symbols) to be added to the output file.  According to the [nvcc documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-altering-compiler-linker-behavior), the description of the `-G` switch is not "generate device debug info" but is actually "generate debug-able device code".

There will be many instances where using the -G switch causes substantially different device code generation.  In this case it appears to inhibit generation of FMA instructions in favor of separate MUL/ADD sequences.

Comment: I submitted a low priority bug report for this because the descriptions for the switch in Nsight for Visual Studio only says, "Generate GPU Debug Information" and "Specifies whether or not GPU debugging information is generated by the CUDA compiler".